# How can I make a report to show only values common to two lists?

Tags: reporting

I essentially am trying to show a list of Accounts which have both Loans and Deposits associated with them. Both of them are Child objects to Account. I was thinking it could be done with a Joined report if I was able to show two blocks - but that would include all of the results, not just ones which land in both blocks.

Is there a way to accomplish this ? Is a Joined report the proper way to do this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Update : Somebody suggested to me to use a rollup field to count the records for each of the type of child objects and to create a formula field which would summarize the two fields, and if each was >0 then the formula field would be "Yes". The report would then filter on that field, thus returning only records with both types of child records.

Comment: if Loans and Deposits are not master-detail but instead lookup relationships, you'll need to use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary package by Andrew Fawcett.   A point-and-click solution

Comment: yes, I think ultimately I will end up getting that tool. I've seen it. Very impressive. Thank you crop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with just the Joined reports since they do not currently support cross object filters, which is what would be required(vote up the idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gMcIAAU)). If you just want to show a list of Accounts that have both Loans and Deposits you could do that with an Account "Matrix, Summary or Tabular" report using 2 cross filters: Accounts with Loans and Accounts with Deposits. That would give you the list of accounts that have both Loans and Deposits.

[image: Cross Filter Option]

[image: Example]

Comment: Jenny - thank you very much for your response. Is your solution using a custom Report Type ? I'm trying to figure out how to have both Loans and Deposits available for that Accounts report. Thanks again.

Comment: @Zoom_v No unfortunately it would not display the data from the loans and deposits, so that is the downfall. It would only find you accounts that had both child objects and potentially whatever fields you rollup from the child objects.

Comment: But that's still the solution for what I was asking about. Thank you very much Jenny !